# Searching table to find multiple records based on input variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, csv

I have a tool that allows a user to tag an account with different words. Its to help keep track of information for the account so they can easily do a search on tags in the future.

For example, there could be 10 accounts in the table and all of them have the keywords New, Payment and Yellow.

On my UI, I would enter multiple keywords as my search and i need it to return all of the accounts that those words are found on.

The problem is I'm using a store procedure and passing the string of words to search such as

```
@var = Yellow,New,Payment
```

I dont think you can do a `WHERE COL IN(@VAR)` so I'm not sure how else to do that.

Comment: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Thanks, a lot of good info on there but still seems like a lot of work to do such a simple task. I will see if i can figure it out

Comment: How are you actually executing the query? In code? What language? Have you looked at using a table variable instead? No string-splitting nonsense, extensible, easier to translate between a DTO and the procedure, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I already did this problem a while ago, this is how i did it,

Var values would be

```
declare @Var varchar(50) = 'Yellow,New,Payment'

Select * from table A
where A.field in  (Select * from dbo.fnSplit(@Var, ',') as i)
```

this my code for function split

```
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](
@sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
 , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
 ) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
 DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
 WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
  BEGIN
    SELECT
     @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX
      (@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX
      (@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

  IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
    INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
  END

 IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
     INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
     RETURN
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following table structure and data:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [AccountID] TINYINT
    ,[KeyWord] NVARCHAR(24)
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([AccountID], [KeyWord])
VALUES (1,'Yellow')
      ,(1,'Red')
      ,(1,'Male')
      ,(2,'Old')
      ,(3,'Yellow')
      ,(3,'Old')
      ,(4,'New')
      ,(4,'Famale')
```

and you are filtering the records using the variable above:

```
DECLARE @SearchKeyWords NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Yellow,Male,Red'
```

The only thing you need is to transform the CSV list into table:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@SearchKeyWords, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>'

SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)')))
FROM @xml.nodes('//r') Tbl(Col)
```

So, this is full working example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [AccountID] TINYINT
    ,[KeyWord] NVARCHAR(24)
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([AccountID], [KeyWord])
VALUES (1,'Yellow')
      ,(1,'Red')
      ,(1,'Male')
      ,(2,'Old')
      ,(3,'Yellow')
      ,(3,'Old')
      ,(4,'New')
      ,(4,'Famale')

DECLARE @SearchKeyWords NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Yellow,Male,Red'

DECLARE @XML XML = N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@SearchKeyWords, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>'


;WITH KeyWords([KeyWord]) AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)')))
    FROM @xml.nodes('//r') Tbl(Col)
)
SELECT DISTINCT [AccountID]
FROM @DataSource DS
INNER JOIN KeyWords KS
    ON DS.[KeyWord] = KS.[KeyWord]
```